# Is there a way to create a .db file in SQLite Database Browser

Tags: database, sqlite

I am using SQLite Database Browser to manage my databases.

However, I can't find a way to create a .db file out of my database.

Here is a picture of the options in SQLite Database Browser.
[image]

In File->Export, I can only create a sql file or a  CSV file.

Is there a way to create a .db file out of SQLite Database Browser ?

If no, is there any other way of doing it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't really have a file extension. By convention, most people use sqlite3 - but you can use anything. Sqlite database is defined by the file format. (See more: http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

Is there something you're trying to accomplish specifically by using the .db format? If not, you can name it .db, or sqlite3, or whatever you'd like.

Comment: I am willing to access it via an Android application, but I think it is going to work without redefining the file extension. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Pierre Did you use .sql file or .sqbpro file in android app ?

Comment: Does cvs work instead of .db in an android application?

Answer (score 4):

Rename `HearthStoneData` to `HearthStoneData.db`.

Comment: Will it really convert the file proprely ?

Comment: And is there a reason why SQLite Database Browser doesn't save the database in that format ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the file you are working on. Do not use  "save as" . The address of the db file is in the top bar. Rename the file in the directory to .db